How to 100% guarantee that my dynamically loaded script is loaded before calling a specific function?
I have a script that is being loaded dynamically in a component. This script has a function that will be used inside another function like window["scriptFunction"]. My problem is that sometimes this function is called before my script is loaded and then we get errors.
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Renderer2, Inject } from '@angular/core';

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   this.script: any;

   public constructor(
      private _renderer2: Renderer2,
      @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: Document
   ) {
       this.someVariable = false;
   }

   public async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
      this.insertDynamicallyScript();
   }

   public ngOnDestroy(): void {
      // after user leave this page I remove the script
      this._renderer2.removeChild(this._document.body, this.script);
   }

   public insertDynamicallyScript(): void {
      this.script = this._renderer2.createElement('script');
      this.script.type = 'text/javascript';
      this.script.src = 'url.here';
      this.script.async = false;
      this._renderer2.appendChild(this._document.body, this.script);
      this.script.onload = () => console.log('Script loaded');
   }

   public userButtonActionFunction(): Promise<void> {
      try {
          if (window['scriptFunction']) {
             await window['scriptFunction'].doSomething();
          } else {
             // script did not load yet and we get here
             // How to make sure that my script is always loaded when I reach this user function?
          }
      } catch (exception) {
         // do something
      } finally {
           // do something
      }
   }
}

I have tried solution on this question but it did not work for me. This problem is happening once in a while, like less than 1% of requests get in this stage. The user interact and click on the button and the function userButtonActionFunction() gets called and the script have not been loaded yet causing some weird behavior on the page.

"How to 100% guarantee that my dynamically loaded script is loaded before calling a specific function?" use ES modules. Why do you use HTML script tags for this?

Sounds like you need to disable the UI element until the function is available...

@jabaa my lack of experience in js.

Instead of fixing your hacky solution, use an import statement to dynamically load an ES module. It returns a promise that is resolved when the module is loaded.

I tried it and got errors with importing it. Error: Cannot find package '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining' imported from ''.

Then, you should try to fix that problem instead of using some hacks.

We can listen for the onLoad event and then execute your code.
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1 id="test">Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  ngOnInit() {
    let node = document.createElement('script');
    node.src =
      'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js';
    node.type = 'text/javascript';
    node.async = true;
    node.charset = 'utf-8';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
    if (node) {
      node.onload = () => {
        console.log('loading done', (window as any).$('#test').text());
      };
    }
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

In the angular.json file, there will be scripts array, include the URL in this array and the function will be available for you to use.
"scripts": [
  "url.here"
]

